# WebView takes too much time to load

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-webview

I am developing an app in which I want to load newspaper link in WebView but the problem is this my WebView  takes too much time to load the newspaper and if I open it in browser then it loads fast.I have coded for web settings also. Please help.

Code :

```
    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);//Use the WebView defined in your layout.
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
    webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);


    final Activity activity = this;
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

        }
    });
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Some error occurred. " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

    });

    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

**In Manifest:**

```
      <application
          android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
```

Comment: could you find a solution to your problem? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

In your manifest file add as below:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <activity ... />
    <activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
</application>
```

In your activity where you are using webview put below code before setContentView():

```
getWindow().setFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
```

Finally, in your code do like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
     webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
}       
else {
     webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

Comment: Do I need to mention <activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" /> in my webview activity  @Hemant as it is not working for me

Comment: <activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" /> by keeping this code you will face video streaming render issue